# How to fix cannot convert argument 1 from `int to `PUCHAR`?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm having trouble with MFC when performing the BULK OUT it says that XferData is invalid

**Error**
[image]

**HEADER FILE is *CyAPI.H***

```
//______________________________________________________________________________
//
// Copyright (c) Cypress Semiconductor, 2011
// All rights reserved.
//
//______________________________________________________________________________

#ifndef CyUSBH
#define CyUSBH

#ifndef   __USB200_H__
#define   __USB200_H__
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct _USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR {
    UCHAR bLength;
    UCHAR bDescriptorType;
    USHORT bcdUSB;
    UCHAR bDeviceClass;
    UCHAR bDeviceSubClass;
    UCHAR bDeviceProtocol;
    UCHAR bMaxPacketSize0;
    USHORT idVendor;
    USHORT idProduct;
    USHORT bcdDevice;
    UCHAR iManufacturer;
    UCHAR iProduct;
    UCHAR iSerialNumber;
    UCHAR bNumConfigurations;
} USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR;

typedef struct _USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR {
    UCHAR bLength;
    UCHAR bDescriptorType;
    UCHAR bEndpointAddress;
    UCHAR bmAttributes;
    USHORT wMaxPacketSize;
    UCHAR bInterval;
} USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR;

typedef struct _USB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR {
    UCHAR bLength;
    UCHAR bDescriptorType;
    USHORT wTotalLength;
    UCHAR bNumInterfaces;
    UCHAR bConfigurationValue;
    UCHAR iConfiguration;
    UCHAR bmAttributes;
    UCHAR MaxPower;
} USB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR;

typedef struct _USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR {
    UCHAR bLength;
    UCHAR bDescriptorType;
    UCHAR bInterfaceNumber;
    UCHAR bAlternateSetting;
    UCHAR bNumEndpoints;
    UCHAR bInterfaceClass;
    UCHAR bInterfaceSubClass;
    UCHAR bInterfaceProtocol;
    UCHAR iInterface;
} USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR;

typedef struct _USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR {
    UCHAR bLength;
    UCHAR bDescriptorType;
    WCHAR bString[1];
} USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR;

typedef struct _USB_COMMON_DESCRIPTOR {
    UCHAR bLength;
    UCHAR bDescriptorType;
} USB_COMMON_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_COMMON_DESCRIPTOR;
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif
//______________________________________________________________________________

class CCyIsoPktInfo {
public:
    LONG Status;
    LONG Length;
};

//______________________________________________________________________________


// {AE18AA60-7F6A-11d4-97DD-00010229B959}
static GUID CYUSBDRV_GUID = {0xae18aa60, 0x7f6a, 0x11d4, 0x97, 0xdd, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x29, 0xb9, 0x59};

typedef enum {TGT_DEVICE, TGT_INTFC, TGT_ENDPT, TGT_OTHER } CTL_XFER_TGT_TYPE;
typedef enum {REQ_STD, REQ_CLASS, REQ_VENDOR } CTL_XFER_REQ_TYPE;
typedef enum {DIR_TO_DEVICE, DIR_FROM_DEVICE } CTL_XFER_DIR_TYPE;
typedef enum {XMODE_BUFFERED, XMODE_DIRECT } XFER_MODE_TYPE;

const int MAX_ENDPTS = 16;
const int MAX_INTERFACES = 8;
const int USB_STRING_MAXLEN = 256;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The CCyEndPoint ABSTRACT Class
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CCyUSBEndPoint
{
protected:
  bool WaitForIO(OVERLAPPED *ovLapStatus);

  virtual PUCHAR BeginDirectXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG bufLen, OVERLAPPED *ov);
  virtual PUCHAR BeginBufferedXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG bufLen, OVERLAPPED *ov);


public:

  CCyUSBEndPoint(void);
  CCyUSBEndPoint(CCyUSBEndPoint& ept);
  CCyUSBEndPoint(HANDLE h, PUSB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR pEndPtDescriptor);

  HANDLE        hDevice;

  // The fields of an EndPoint Descriptor
  UCHAR  DscLen;
  UCHAR  DscType;
  UCHAR  Address;
  UCHAR  Attributes;
  USHORT MaxPktSize;
  USHORT PktsPerFrame;
  UCHAR  Interval;

  // Other fields
  ULONG  TimeOut;
  ULONG  UsbdStatus;
  ULONG  NtStatus;

  DWORD  bytesWritten;
  DWORD  LastError;
  bool   bIn;

  XFER_MODE_TYPE   XferMode;

  bool    XferData(PUCHAR buf, LONG &len, CCyIsoPktInfo* pktInfos = NULL);
  bool    XferData(PUCHAR buf, LONG &bufLen, CCyIsoPktInfo* pktInfos, bool pktMode);
  virtual PUCHAR BeginDataXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG len, OVERLAPPED *ov) = 0;
  virtual bool FinishDataXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG &len, OVERLAPPED *ov, PUCHAR pXmitBuf, CCyIsoPktInfo* pktInfos = NULL);
  bool    WaitForXfer(OVERLAPPED *ov, ULONG tOut);
  ULONG   GetXferSize(void);
  void    SetXferSize(ULONG xfer);

  bool Reset(void);
  bool Abort(void);

private:



};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The Control Endpoint Class
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CCyControlEndPoint : public CCyUSBEndPoint
{
private:

public:
  CCyControlEndPoint(void);
  CCyControlEndPoint(CCyControlEndPoint& ept);
  CCyControlEndPoint(HANDLE h, PUSB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR pEndPtDescriptor);

  CTL_XFER_TGT_TYPE Target;
  CTL_XFER_REQ_TYPE ReqType;
  CTL_XFER_DIR_TYPE Direction;

  UCHAR             ReqCode;
  WORD              Value;
  WORD              Index;

  bool Read(PUCHAR buf, LONG &len);
  bool Write(PUCHAR buf, LONG &len);
  PUCHAR BeginDataXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG len, OVERLAPPED *ov);
};



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The Isoc Endpoint Class
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CCyIsocEndPoint : public CCyUSBEndPoint
{

protected:
  virtual PUCHAR BeginDirectXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG bufLen, OVERLAPPED *ov);
  virtual PUCHAR BeginBufferedXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG bufLen, OVERLAPPED *ov);

public:
  CCyIsocEndPoint(void);
  CCyIsocEndPoint(HANDLE h, PUSB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR pEndPtDescriptor);

  PUCHAR BeginDataXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG len, OVERLAPPED *ov);
  CCyIsoPktInfo* CreatePktInfos(LONG bufLen, int &packets);

};



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The Bulk Endpoint Class
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CCyBulkEndPoint : public CCyUSBEndPoint
{
public:
  CCyBulkEndPoint(void);
  CCyBulkEndPoint(HANDLE h, PUSB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR pEndPtDescriptor);

  PUCHAR BeginDataXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG len, OVERLAPPED *ov);
};



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The Interrupt Endpoint Class
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CCyInterruptEndPoint : public CCyUSBEndPoint
{
public:
  CCyInterruptEndPoint(void);
  CCyInterruptEndPoint(HANDLE h, PUSB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR pEndPtDescriptor);

  PUCHAR BeginDataXfer(PUCHAR buf, LONG len, OVERLAPPED *ov);
};



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The Interface Class
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CCyUSBInterface
{
private:
protected:
public:
  CCyUSBEndPoint *EndPoints[MAX_ENDPTS];  // Holds pointers to all the interface's endpoints, plus a pointer to the Control endpoint zero

  UCHAR bLength;
  UCHAR bDescriptorType;
  UCHAR bInterfaceNumber;
  UCHAR bAlternateSetting;
  UCHAR bNumEndpoints;           // Not counting the control endpoint
  UCHAR bInterfaceClass;
  UCHAR bInterfaceSubClass;
  UCHAR bInterfaceProtocol;
  UCHAR iInterface;

  UCHAR bAltSettings;
  USHORT wTotalLength;          // Needed in case Intfc has additional (non-endpt) descriptors


  CCyUSBInterface(HANDLE h, PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR pIntfcDescriptor);
  CCyUSBInterface(CCyUSBInterface& ifc);  // Copy Constructor
  ~CCyUSBInterface(void);

};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The Config Class
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CCyUSBConfig
{
private:

protected:
public:
  CCyUSBInterface *Interfaces[MAX_INTERFACES];

  UCHAR bLength;
  UCHAR bDescriptorType;
  USHORT wTotalLength;
  UCHAR bNumInterfaces;
  UCHAR bConfigurationValue;
  UCHAR iConfiguration;
  UCHAR bmAttributes;
  UCHAR MaxPower;

  UCHAR AltInterfaces;


  CCyUSBConfig(void);
  CCyUSBConfig(CCyUSBConfig& cfg);  // Copy Constructor
  CCyUSBConfig(HANDLE h, PUSB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR pConfigDescr);
  ~CCyUSBConfig(void);



};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The USB Device Class - This is the main class that contains members of all the
// other classes.
//
// To use the library, create an instance of this Class and call it's Open method
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CCyUSBDevice
{
// The public members are accessible (i.e. corruptible) by the user of the library
// Algorithms of the class don't rely on any public members.  Instead, they use the
// private members of the class for their calculations.

public:

  CCyUSBDevice(HANDLE hnd = NULL, GUID guid = CYUSBDRV_GUID, BOOL bOpen = true);
  ~CCyUSBDevice(void);

  CCyUSBEndPoint      **EndPoints;     // Shortcut to USBCfgs[CfgNum]->Interfaces[IntfcIndex]->Endpoints
  CCyUSBEndPoint       *EndPointOf(UCHAR addr);

  CCyControlEndPoint   *ControlEndPt;
  CCyIsocEndPoint      *IsocInEndPt;
  CCyIsocEndPoint      *IsocOutEndPt;
  CCyBulkEndPoint      *BulkInEndPt;
  CCyBulkEndPoint      *BulkOutEndPt;
  CCyInterruptEndPoint *InterruptInEndPt;
  CCyInterruptEndPoint *InterruptOutEndPt;

  USHORT                StrLangID;
  ULONG                 UsbdStatus;
  ULONG                 NtStatus;
  ULONG                 DriverVersion;
  ULONG                 USBDIVersion;
  char                  DeviceName[USB_STRING_MAXLEN];
  char                  FriendlyName[USB_STRING_MAXLEN];
  wchar_t               Manufacturer[USB_STRING_MAXLEN];
  wchar_t               Product[USB_STRING_MAXLEN];
  wchar_t               SerialNumber[USB_STRING_MAXLEN];

  CHAR                  DevPath[USB_STRING_MAXLEN];

  USHORT                BcdUSB;
  USHORT                VendorID;
  USHORT                ProductID;
  UCHAR                 USBAddress;
  UCHAR                 DevClass;
  UCHAR                 DevSubClass;
  UCHAR                 DevProtocol;
  UCHAR                 MaxPacketSize;
  USHORT                BcdDevice;

  UCHAR                 ConfigValue;
  UCHAR                 ConfigAttrib;
  UCHAR                 MaxPower;

  UCHAR                 IntfcClass;
  UCHAR                 IntfcSubClass;
  UCHAR                 IntfcProtocol;
  bool                  bHighSpeed;

  DWORD                 BytesXfered;


  UCHAR                 DeviceCount(void);
  UCHAR                 ConfigCount(void);
  UCHAR                 IntfcCount(void);
  UCHAR                 AltIntfcCount(void);
  UCHAR                 EndPointCount(void);

  UCHAR                 Config(void)     { return CfgNum; }    // Normally 0
  void                  SetConfig(UCHAR cfg);

  UCHAR                 Interface(void)  { return IntfcNum; }  // Usually 0
                        // No SetInterface method since only 1 intfc per device (per Windows)

  UCHAR                 AltIntfc(void);
  bool                  SetAltIntfc(UCHAR alt);

  GUID                  DriverGUID(void) { return DrvGuid; }
  HANDLE                DeviceHandle(void) { return hDevice; }
  void                  UsbdStatusString(ULONG stat, PCHAR s);
  bool                  CreateHandle(UCHAR dev);
  void                  DestroyHandle();


  bool                  Open(UCHAR dev);
  void                  Close(void);
  bool                  Reset(void);
  bool                  ReConnect(void);
  bool                  Suspend(void);
  bool                  Resume(void);
  bool                  IsOpen(void)      { return (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE); }

  UCHAR                 PowerState(void);


  void                  GetDeviceDescriptor(PUSB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR descr);
  void                  GetConfigDescriptor(PUSB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR descr);
  void                  GetIntfcDescriptor(PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR descr);
  CCyUSBConfig          GetUSBConfig(int index);


private:

  USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR         USBDeviceDescriptor;
  PUSB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR USBConfigDescriptors[2];

  CCyUSBConfig                 *USBCfgs[2];

  HANDLE                        hWnd;
  HANDLE                        hDevice;
  HANDLE                        hDevNotification;
  HANDLE                        hHndNotification;

  GUID                          DrvGuid;

  UCHAR                         Devices;
  UCHAR                         Interfaces;
  UCHAR                         AltInterfaces;
  UCHAR                         Configs;

  UCHAR                         DevNum;
  UCHAR                         CfgNum;
  UCHAR                         IntfcNum;     // The current selected interface's bInterfaceNumber
  UCHAR                         IntfcIndex;   // The entry in the Config's interfaces table matching to IntfcNum and AltSetting

  void                          GetDevDescriptor(void);
  void                          GetCfgDescriptor(int descIndex);
  void                          GetString(wchar_t *s, UCHAR sIndex);
  void                          SetStringDescrLanguage(void);
  void                          SetAltIntfcParams(UCHAR alt);
  bool                          IoControl(ULONG cmd, PUCHAR buf, ULONG len);

  void                          SetEndPointPtrs(void);
  void                          GetDeviceName(void);
  void                          GetFriendlyName(void);
  void                          GetDriverVer(void);
  void                          GetUSBDIVer(void);
  void                          GetSpeed(void);
  void                          GetUSBAddress(void);
  //void                          CloseEndPtHandles(void);

  bool                          RegisterForPnpEvents(HANDLE h);
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

**CODE**

```
// MFCApplication2Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication2.h"
#include "MFCApplication2Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "CyAPI.h"
#include "Periph.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include "UART.h"



#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

bool IsConnect = false;
// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication2Dlg dialog



CMFCApplication2Dlg::CMFCApplication2Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCApplication2Dlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication2Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication2Dlg message handlers

BOOL CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

    USBDevice->Open(0);

    if (USBDevice->IsOpen() != TRUE)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to Open Device"));
    }
    else
    {
        IsConnect = true;
    }
}


void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    USBDevice->Close();
    IsConnect = false;
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    TCHAR tmpUart[60];
    long OutPacketSize;
    OutPacketSize = sizeof(sUart);

    LPTSTR pBuffer;
    CString sBuffer;

    int i;

    if (IsConnect == false)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("USB Connect Fail"));
        return;
    }

    CEdit *OutValue = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_OUT_VALUE);

    pBuffer = sBuffer.GetBuffer(60);
    OutValue->GetWindowText(pBuffer, 60);

    _tcscpy(tmpUart, pBuffer);

    OutPacketSize = _tcslen(tmpUart);

    for (i = 0; i<OutPacketSize; i++) sUart[i] = tmpUart[i];

    sUart[OutPacketSize + 1] = 0;
    OutPacketSize = OutPacketSize + 1;

    // Perform the BULK OUT

    if (USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt)
    {
        USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt->XferData(sUart, OutPacketSize);
    }

}
```

This function here will perform the bulk out event. But there seems to be a problem in the XferData(bool) in checking the `int[60]` to `PUCHAR`. What is the right declaration of the `sUart` variable to match with the `long OutPacketSize` I think `int sUart[60]` is incorrect. Please help me with this one, I'm new to *Microsoft Foundation Classes* (MFC)

```
void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    int sUart[60];

    TCHAR tmpUart[60];
    long OutPacketSize;
    OutPacketSize = sizeof(sUart);

    LPTSTR pBuffer;
    CString sBuffer;

    int i;

    if (IsConnect == false)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("USB Connect Fail"));
        return;
    }

    CEdit *OutValue = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_OUT_VALUE);

    pBuffer = sBuffer.GetBuffer(60);
    OutValue->GetWindowText(pBuffer, 60);

    wcscpy_s(tmpUart, pBuffer);

    OutPacketSize = _tcslen(tmpUart);

    for (i = 0; i<OutPacketSize; i++) sUart[i] = tmpUart[i];

    sUart[OutPacketSize + 1] = 0;
    OutPacketSize = OutPacketSize + 1;

    // Perform the BULK OUT

    if (USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt)
    {
        USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt->XferData(sUart, OutPacketSize);
    }

}
```

Comment: `PUCHAR` is a pointer to `unsigned char`. That's not the same as a pointer to `int`. Why do you expect them to match?

Comment: so I will change `int` to `PUCHAR` declaration sir? But there seems to be an error instead when I declared it. Can you help me? Please I need an answer.

Comment: It wants an array of bytes, you are passing an array of ints.  Pretty plain type mismatch of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the integer you're passing makes sense to the called function, I would expect the following to work:

```
USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt->XferData(reinterpret_cast<PUCHAR>(sUart), OutPacketSize);
```